# In Python, is it possible to call a method after a yield statement?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a for loop that includes a yield statement and then a print statement after. The print statement doesn't get called.

I'd like to include a function call to delete a variable (once I use it, after the yield statement), so I'm wondering if it's possible to make function call after a yield.

Comment: Why do you want to delete variable? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execution of the generator resumes when you get the next value:

```
def gen():
    while True:
        yield 1
        print("After yield")

g = gen()
a = next(g)  # prints nothing
b = next(g)  # prints "After yield"
c = next(g)  # prints "After yield"
```

What do you mean by "delete a variable"?  The most you can do is reduce the reference count of that object, which will happen anyways if you either reassign the reference in the generator to something else, or when the generator object is garbage collected.